# How to navigate through the jquery tabs with links outside the tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, hyperlink

I am searching and tweaking all the day to fix this issue. I have searched the whole stackoverflow forum for the solutions that is fitting to my situation.

I have 5 tabs on my homepage. I would like to use links outside the tab to jump to and open the desired tab. When I click on Tab2 it jumps to the top of the page but it wont open tab2 it stays on tab1 (HOME tab). How to fix this?

Link to specific tab:

```
<a href="#" goto="tab2">Tab2</a>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="tabContaier">

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#tab1">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">OPTIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul><!-- //Tab buttons -->

    <div class="tabDetails">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabContents">
                <h1>Title1</h1>
                <iframe src="Home.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab1 -->
        <div id="tab2" class="tabContents">
                <h1>Title2  </h1>
                <h2>  </h2>
                <h3>  </h3>
                <iframe src="Services.html" width="1150" height="640" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab2 -->
        <div id="tab3" class="tabContents">
               <h1>Title3</h1>
               <iframe src="Options.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab3 -->
        <div id="tab4" class="tabContents">
            <h1>Title4 </h1>
            <iframe src="Aboutus.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab4 -->
        <div id="tab5" class="tabContents">
            <h1>Title5</h1>
           <iframe src="Contactus.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab5 -->
    </div><!-- //tab Details -->
</div><!-- //Tab Container -->
```

CSS:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Tab</title>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:10; padding:0;}

body{

    font:normal 14px/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a{outline:none;}

#tabContaier{
    background:#f0f0f0;
    border:1x solid #fff;
    margin:100px auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    width:1315px;
}
    #tabContaier ul{
        overflow:hidden;
        border-left:0px solid #fff;
        height:80px;
        position:center;
        z-index:100;
    }
    #tabContaier li{
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
    #tabContaier li a{
        background:#ddd;
        border:3px solid #ffff;
        border-left:0;
        color:#666;
        cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
        height:35px;
        line-height:35px;
        padding:0 98px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:bold;
    }
    #tabContaier li a:hover{
        background:#fff;
    }
    #tabContaier li a.active{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:px solid #fff;
        border-right:px;
        color:#333;
    }
    .tabDetails{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        margin:34px px;
    }
    .tabContents{
        padding:px

}
    .tabContents h1{
        font:normal 24px/1.1em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        padding:0 0 px;
                                width:auto;



</style>
```

JAVASCRIPTCODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Hide all tab conten divs by default
    $(".tabContents").hide(); 

    // Show the first div of tab content by default
    $(".tabContents:first").show(); 

    //Fire the click event
    $("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(){ 

        // Catch the click link
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 

        // Remove pre-highlighted link
        $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active"); 

        // set clicked link to highlight state
        $(this).addClass("active");         

        // hide currently visible tab content div
        $(".tabContents").hide(); 

        // show the target tab content div by matching clicked link.
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
 return true;

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why you don't just use [**jQuery UI tabs**](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov maybe he wants to make custom tabs

Comment: I hope someone on this forum can help me to solve this problem. Otherwise I would try your solution  @EvgeniyNaydenov

Comment: Seems to work for me, but notice I am using jQuery 1.7.2. Is there a reason you are using 1.4.2 ? You have not included the css, so the tabs don't look like tabs, but checkout this jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/etasep/1/

Comment: @ShaggyInjun 
I have updated my post see above for the css code. Could you send me a new jsbin link with this time the css code implemented. I am really curious because you have sad that it is working for you?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Notice your url's are relative and wont work on JSBin. So you are not seeing the content you hope to see inside the tab.

http://jsbin.com/etasep/2#tab1

Comment: @ShaggyInjun Navigation by clicking on the tabs just works fine. However when use the < a href code ( see above fort the code) it just jumps to the top of the page and it stays on the home tab. I would like to open and to jump to a tab by clicking on a link that is stationed outside the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery and html seems fine, you should have problem from jQuery 1.4 version.

If you want an url response to your tabs, use this:

```
var anchor = window.location.hash;//returns url hash only like: '#tab4'

if ( anchor.length > 1 ) {
    $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active"); 
    $('a[href="' + anchor + '"]').addClass('active');

    $(anchor).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the response @barlas. I have put your code after return true; . But it did not work. It jumps to the top of the page but it stays again on the home tab and its not opening the for example the services tab (tab2). Maybe I have put your code in the wrong place?

Comment: @StajeBaa My sample not for click response, it's just url response when page loaded. Do you must use jQuery 1.4.2 ? Can you update your jQuery and try it again.

Comment: Yes I have updated it to 1.7.2. However I cannot open a specific tab using a link. Navigating through the tabs just by clicking on the tabs works fine. But I would also like to navigate through the tabs with links- these links are outside the tabs. These links are stationed at the bottom of my webpage (footer). For example when a visitor clicks on a link - that is stationed at the bottom of the page- then it must open and jump to the specific tab.

Comment: This is what I want, see this Jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/TGMDd/7/. You clearly see a link that is placed outside the tabs. When You click on the ''go to services'' link, it opens the right tab.

Comment: @StajeBaa Problem solved: http://jsfiddle.net/TGMDd/32/ it was scrolling to id that refers, which was possible by length.

Comment: The jsfiddle that I provided is just an example of what I want. How can tweak my code that I posted here that will work just like the jsfiddle example?